# Confusing double negative in verbiage on user prefs page

Tags: support, user-interface, preferences, help-text

On my user prefs page, under the "Miscellaneous" heading, I spied this:

[image: Screenshot]

Two questions:

- Is the second option talking about **email** notifications or some other kind of notification?
- Why is one checkbox an opt-in and the other an opt-out?

Assuming both refer to *email* notifications, I suggest it may be less confusing to change the header to "Email Notifications" and invert the state/label of the second option.

(And yeah, I know this is a silly nitpick.)

Comment: So...you can either agree to receiving eMail notifications, or opt out of receiving site notifications?   ...Makes sense, but the wording is a little strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second is not for email notifications.  It is for the notification bar that occasionally appears at the top of the site (like when you earn a badge, for instance).